# Saving XML using SQL

Tags: xml

How can I save a XML which is generated by SQL Query locally on my machine?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Also, can you give an example?

Comment: I have a table in sql say Students  and I have two Columns StudentID and StudentName,  I have a query which generates the XML with Students as a root and Student as an element with id and name. So I have an XML now with the query now how can I save this XML in to my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is just structured text. You save it like you would save any text.

When you are reading your dataset, you would assign the text of the XML field to a variable of some type, in the simplest case a string variable, generally if you want to do something with the XML you would assign it to a helper class that will have methods that allow you to navigate the XML. Often if you are reading the XML by some helper class the helper class will simply have a save method. For example XElement or XDocument in .NET's Linq to XML has a save method.

If you need more specific help, you will need to amend your question to be more specific about how you are reading your data, what language you are using etc.